# Meaning of "\.08V" vs "V" in Raw Expression

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

There have been a few times where the Raw Expression of a Cell seems to have changed between uses.

A recent example I have found is the following.

I have a cell that starts off as:

```
V = 0.1;
tt = 300;
```

With a raw expression of that is approximated by:

```
Cell[BoxData[{
 RowBox[{
  RowBox[{"V", "=", "0.1"}], ";"}], "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
 RowBox[{
  RowBox[{"tt", "=", " ", "300"}], ";"}]}], "Input"]
```

The visual appearance of the cell does not change but the raw expression has a slight modification.

```
Cell[BoxData[{
 RowBox[{
  RowBox[{"\.08V", "=", "0.1"}], ";"}], "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
 RowBox[{
  RowBox[{"tt", " ", "=", " ", "300"}], ";"}]}], "Input"]
```

The change being "V"->".08V".  This sometimes happens with multiple variables and breaks the expression.

What is the meaning of the ".08" part of ".08V"? Why is it unexpectedly added to my notebooks on occasion?

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using?  On what platform?  \.08 is the unicode/ascii code for the backspace character.  This sounds vaguely familiar as a bug in some older version of Mathematica for Mac.

Answer (score 3):

`\.08` is a two digit hexadecimal [character escape code](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/CharacterCodes.html#18479).  On my system it is a diamond in a rectangle.  I don't know why it would be inserted into your notebook.

Answer (score 3):

You get that escape code character when you use the US international keyboard on a PC, which has this 'dead letter' system to create accents. On this type of keyboard if you type a double quote you don't see anything at first but if you then enter an "a" you get an a-umlaut: ä.

Anyway, the specific character .08 comes into existence in MMA when you type a double quote, another letter that does not combine with this quote to an accent letter (so, no a, o u etc), then type a second -dead- quote and backspace erase that second quote *before it becomes visible by following it with another character*. So, if you type

"s"<kbd>backspace</kbd>

for instance, you get this character.

e'<kbd>backspace</kbd>

works too. I think you just made a typo somewhere without noticing.

Comment: Any way for me to check what type of keyboard I am using with mathematica. I do not see "On this type of keyboard if you type a double quote you don't see anything at first but if you then enter an "a" you get an a-umlaut: ä" ever happening. I tried "s"backspace and could not reproduce anything other then normal characters being deleted. It does not make sense for it to be typo because in-between closing and opening a notebook \.08 can appear in front of many variables in the program and breaks a working program they still show the last results in the results sub cell even.

Comment: @Davorak The above reads "the US international keyboard on a **PC**". In your question you didn't state the platform you were using.

Comment: @Davorak However, on a mac (I believe using an English international keyboard) you can recreate similar behavior if you press alt-u backspace. Try //FullForm on the result and you'll see the \.08 (it's invisible on a mac, but visible on a PC).